# File gets truncated (not deleted) from current working directory

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I have this script verbatim, for some reason this script is truncated a file in the pwd, and I am not sure why:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;
cat run.r2g.internal.sh > "$(npm bin -g)/r2g"
```

when I run it, the local file `run.r2g.internal.sh` consistently gets truncated.

That file is really only reference by this line:

```
cat run.r2g.internal.sh > "$(npm bin -g)/r2g"
```

When I omit that line, the file is not truncated...
anyone know why that line would truncate the file? So weird.

Comment: I determined that that half of the code wasn't causing the problem, so trimmed it down

Comment: I did it from my other account by accident lol

Comment: OK, now split that line into two: `name="$(npm bin -g)/r2g"; cat run.r2g.internal.sh > "$name"` and see which one does it.

Comment: ok gonna try that thanks

Comment: yeah it's the cat command that does it

Comment: It's almost as if when I write to "$(npm bin -g)/r2g" it makes the source into a symlink or something

Comment: Maybe one of them is already a symlink. I'd check `name="$(npm bin -g)/r2g"; ls -l run.r2g.internal.sh "$name"`.

Comment: if I delete `"$(npm bin -g)/r2g"` beforehand, the problem goes away, is that a clue?